# CRC16 Reverse in C166 Arch

Tags: ida, disassembly, static-analysis, crc, c166

Before that I asked about piece of code that used in this algorithm ([here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25824/the-c166-family-code-meaning)). Now I have a bit problem with the rest of algorithm.
So I have to describe this with detail. Sorry if i vast your time for read it.
I have shown an algorithm below. It seems is a CRC16 algorithm.

```
CRC_16_Calculate:                       
                                        
                mov     [-r0], r9
                mov     [-r0], r8
                mov     [-r0], r7
                mov     [-r0], r6
                mov     r9, r12
                mov     r8, r15
                jmpr    cc_UC, loc_29D6
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_29A4:                               
                mov     r4, r13
                mov     r5, r14
                add     r13, #1
                addc    r14, #0
                exts    r5, #1
                movb    rl3, [r4]
                movbz   r7, rl3
                movb    rl6, #0

loc_29B4:                               
                mov     r4, r9
                xor     r4, r7
                and     r4, #1
                jmpr    cc_Z, loc_29C8
                mov     r4, r9
                shr     r4, #1
                xor     r4, #0A001h
                mov     r9, r4
                jmpr    cc_UC, loc_29CA
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_29C8:                               
                shr     r9, #1

loc_29CA:                               
                shr     r7, #1
                addb    rl6, #1
                cmpb    rl6, #8
                jmpr    cc_C, loc_29B4
                sub     r8, #1

loc_29D6:                               
                cmp     r8, #0
                jmpr    cc_UGT, loc_29A4
                mov     r4, r9
                mov     r6, [r0+]
                mov     r7, [r0+]
                mov     r8, [r0+]
                mov     r9, [r0+]
                rets
```

As you see in below I converted that to C++ code:

```
static uint16_t intCrc16(uint8_t* cBuffer)
{
    uint16_t wPreset = 0xFFFF;
    uint16_t iBufLen = 6;
    uint16_t temp = 0;
    while (iBufLen--)
    {
        temp = *cBuffer++;
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if ((wPreset ^ temp) & 0x01) wPreset = (wPreset >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
            else wPreset >>= 1;
            temp >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return wPreset;
}
```

It seems everything is good but the problem appear right here. The main loop of this function run for 6 times(`iBufLen`) but
the input argument(`cBuffer`) length is always 4 Bytes. To prove this point we check where this algorithm invoked. Look at below:

```
mov     r13, r4
mov     r14, r5
mov     r15, #6
calls   0, CRC_16_Calculate
```

As you see, `r13` and `r14` are input argument as `cBuffer` and `r15` equivalent to `iBufLen`.
So, what's my mistake?
By the way, `r4` and `r5` are the returned value of function that I pointed ([here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25824/the-c166-family-code-meaning)).

Comment: Please paste the code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: Thanks dear Igor. But how I can paste Ida diagrams as Text? Each code pasted as Text, only diagram is as screenshot.

Comment: you can paste the text listing, it doesn't have to be a graph.

Comment: OK. Sure. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there’s a mistake in your conversion?

Comment: Because, `iBufLen` is 6 but I only give 4 bytes to the input(`cBuffer`). Does memory leakage occur?

Comment: It seems the original code expects 6 bytes so you should provide 6 bytes